# Notification bar click to close app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notification-bar

How can I close app when user clicks on text in notification bar without displaying any window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code and register broadcast receiver in your activity :

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)_context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);   

Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"",System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


Context context = _context.getApplicationContext();


/** Set the intent extras to be passed to calling activity*/
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("action_close_app");



/** Create a pending intent, requires to generate a notification */

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcase(
  _context.getApplicationContext(), requestCode,
  notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


/** Set notification with required fields */

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "", "", contentIntent);



/** notify manager to generate notification on status bar*/

mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works great! I wished there was a more elegant solution for someone who comes from vb6 days.

Answer (score 1):

create the notification use `getBroadcast`

`Intent intent = new Intent("action_close_app");`

`PendingIntent closeIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, flags)`

when you click the notification, will send a broadcast with the action `action_close_app`, you need register a broadcast receiver to process `action_close_app` receive, just close your app.