# How can I create notification which will close the app after clicking?

Tags: java, android, notifications

How can I create simple notification, which will close the application (in multitasking) after click? Thanks. (Java, Android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification bar click to close app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222406/notification-bar-click-to-close-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first we should create notification that call an activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourClass.class);
intent.putExtra("NotiClick",true);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    Notification Noti;
    Noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("YourTitle")
            .setContentText("YourDescription")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true).build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, Noti);
}
```

Then in the **onCreate()** of your class do this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if(extras == null) 
{
    //not being clicked on
} 
else if (extras.getBoolean("NotiClick"))
{
    //being clicked
}
```

and for completely close application you can kill process :

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```